# HTML5 + Javascript on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need some help. I decided to write a simple game with javascript and HTML. So I followed this tutorial. http://billmill.org/static/canvastutorial/ It works perfectly on computer, bu now, I want it to run on my Android phone. (ICS 4.0.3). But it doesn't work. It just show the bricks and the paddle, and the ball moves, but I cant move the paddle. I also include jQuery mobile, but it doesn't work anyway. What else should I change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial does not support mobile events. Only keyboard and mouse, which neither is supported on mobile phones.

You should use touch events instead or you could "fake" a keyboard by adding 2 buttons and give them `click` events.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there any tutorial that show how to "convert" from keyboard and mouse to touch events?

Comment: @MatejMohar: Just add extra event listeners to your code. Use `touchstart, touchend` and `touchmove` instead of `mousedown, mouseup` and `mousemove`.